# Пропал пункт запуск от им. администратора

Tags: windows-7

Система windows 7

В общем такая беда, недавно переустановил систему и начал устанавливать нужный софт, некоторые файлы просят запуск от имени администратора (обычно он в контекстном меню) но у меня у некоторых файлов его просто нет там, даже с зажатой клавишей shift этот пункт не появляется. Я погуглил как полагается и нашел схожие проблемы, но у ребят либо он вовсе пропадал отовсюду либо не корректно работал на гостевом аккаунте, у меня же аккаунт один и я думал он и есть админитраторский. Повторюсь пропал пункт "Запуск от имени администратора" у некоторых файлов (не у всех) Так как я с реестром на "Вы" я не рискнул что то менять поэтому пришел сюда, может что то пововетуете.

Comment: На время решения данной проблемы, чтоб запустить все ж нужно как админ - достаточно снизить уровень UAC... он где-то примерно в `панель управления -> Безопасность и обслуживание -> изменение параметров контроля учетных записей -> никогда не уведомлять`  http://windowstune.ru/win7/tuning7/kak-otklyuchit-uac-v-windows-7.html ..........если очень сильно надо запустить......................... если нажать `win+R` и вбить команду `services.msc` чтоб открылось окно служб....... есть там служба `secondary Logon` ??

Comment: Кстати, чтоб в реестре копаться - можно сделать бэкап реестра и в случае чего вернуть все как было.....ну или же сделать бэкап системы на всякий случай....чтоб всегда можно было к чему-то вернуться... сделайте бэкапы и попробуйте что-то с реестром сделать. например  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/200558-run-administrator-add-remove-context-menu-windows-7-a.html

Comment: у `*.msi` файлов нет данного пункта. Windows Installer сам запрашивает повышение прав. В `*.exe`-файлах система не различает инсталлятор и обычную программу, поэтому пункт запуска от имени администратора должен быть в наличии.

Comment: @rdorn Благодарю за разъяснение, как оказалось не доглядел что файл не .exe

Comment: тогда перенесу в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у `*.msi` файлов нет данного пункта. Windows Installer сам запрашивает повышение прав. В `*.exe`-файлах система не различает инсталлятор и обычную программу, поэтому пункт запуска от имени администратора должен быть в наличии.